# Navigation.findNavController().navigate() isn't working

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I put Navhost to xml.And I put 2 button to same xml.I have 2 fragment.Button's job is passing a fragment to other fragment.And my xml's class is

```
class User_Profile_Page : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityUserProfilePageBinding
    private var fragmentStatus : Int =0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding=ActivityUserProfilePageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view=binding.root
        setContentView(view)
    }
   fun posts_button(){
        if(fragmentStatus!=0){
            val action=PostListFragmentDirections.actionPostListFragmentToLikedPostFragment()
            println("deneme deneme fragment")
            Navigation.findNavController(binding.fragmentContainerView3).navigate(action)
            fragmentStatus=0
            }
    }
    fun liked_button(){
        if(fragmentStatus!=1){
            val action=LikedPostFragmentDirections.actionLikedPostFragmentToPostListFragment()
            println("deneme deneme fragment2")
            Navigation.findNavController(binding.fragmentContainerView3).navigate(action)
            fragmentStatus=1
        }
    }
}
```

`posts_button` and `liked_button` are `onClick` methods.
And when I run this , I'm getting

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick"
```

I tried changing `navhost`.